# Preciso de ajuda com o ActivityIndicator no Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin-forms

Tenho uma aplicação que trabalha juntamente com um servidor, onde ela precisa buscar alguns dados.

Quando faço essa busca, geralmente demora um certo tempo e gostaria de colocar um `ActivityIndicator` enquanto o carregamento ocorre.

Fiz da seguinte forma:

```html
<ActivityIndicator x:Name="ActivityLoad" IsRunning="False" IsVisible="False"/>
```

E no código, fiz com que quando ele clicasse no botão de login, deixasse o `ActivityIndicator` visível.
Porém, durante a requisição para o servidor a aplicação simplesmente trava, congela tudo, até que o servidor retorne uma resposta. Fazendo com que o `ActivityIndicator` só apareça na tela quando já carregou. Isso acontece em todas as rotinas que tenho. (Tentei usar o `Async` e o `Await` mas não funcionou)

Pesquisei em vários lugares e ainda não consegui resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que isso resolve o seu problema

No XAML

```
<ActivityIndicator x:Name="ActivityLoad" IsRunning="True" Opacity="0"/>
```

No .cs (c# back)

```
public async void ClickMethod(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
   //fazer aparecer
   await ActivityLoad.FadeTo(1,300);


   //aqui você coloca o metodo de busca

   //fazer sumir
   await ActivityLoad.FadeTo(0,300);

}
```

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou. Continuei procurando e usei o Rg.Popup, um nuget no projeto. Dessa forma, criei um popup transparente com o activity indicator rodando. Cada vez que preciso carregar, chamo o popup pra tela, depois fecho. Ficou um pouco gambiarra mas é a unica maneira que encontrei de não travar tudo durante a solicitação no servidor.

Answer (score -1):

A chamada para o seu servidor é assíncrono? Se não estiver assíncrono provavelmente ele vai congelar mesmo, tente deixar a chamada para o server assíncrono.

Antes de chamar o método que faz a requisição coloque o `ActivityIndicator` para

```
IsRunning = True 
IsVisible = True
```

E quando ele terminar a requisição coloque abaixo do método

```
IsRunning = false
IsVisible = false
```